# How can I override attachBaseContext in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this method that works fine in `Activity`s. But how do I use it in fragments?

```
@Override
public void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Changing `protected` to `public` doesn't work, what else can I try? I get an error indicating it does not override the subclass. I found nothing on StackOverflow about this.

Comment: Did you set up this on onCreate method of your application? Moreover if it is working on activity then it should be working on fragment too .

Comment: @shuvro I'm trying to override a method... What do you mean "set up this on onCreate of the application"?

Comment: You tried to use custom font for your entire application am I right ?

Comment: @shuvro correct, and I need to override this method on all the activities. Do I have to override it on fragments too?

Comment: No you dont need to override it on fragment , check my answer . The way I have set it up and I am using version 2.2.0 of this library

Answer (score 2):

This method only applied to the Activity. Notice that Fragments extend from the Activity . So you need over writer this method in ***related activity of fragment***.